# Saving own Types inside Arrays

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran95

I'm having a problem compiling a program with GFortran, or two to be precise.

First, my code is:

```
Type :: zeit
    INTEGER :: Stunde, Minute
    real :: Sekunde
END Type

TYPE :: ergebnis
    CHARACTER(LEN=30):: Nachname, Vorname
    TYPE(Zeit)::Laufzeit
END TYPE

type(ergebnis), allocatable :: Liste(:)
```

Which contains these:

```
SUBROUTINE leseliste(k)
    type(ergebnis) :: Liste
    integer :: i, k
    character(len=30) :: vorN, nachN
    integer :: stun, minu
    real :: seku


    do i=1, k
        WRITE (*, *) "Laeufername und Zeit:"
        Read (*, *) vorN, nachN, stun, minu, seku
        Liste(i:1) = ergebnis(vorN, nachN, zeit(stu, minu, seku))
    enddo
END SUBROUTINE
```

I then allocate my List with a read variable and call the leseliste-subroutine.

But GFortran won't compile because:

```
Aufgabe14.f95:33:3:

Liste(i:1) = Laeufer(vorN, nachN, Ergebnislaeufer(stu, minu, seku))
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
Aufgabe14.f95:41:5:

USE Zeitmodul
 1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file ‘zeitmodul.mod’ for reading at (1):   Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
compilation terminated.
```

Anyone, who can help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `liste` isn't an array when you `liste(i:1`)`. What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Sorry, changed the names. Corrected it, still same result...

Comment: @francescalus but isn't it because of `type(ergebnis), allocatable :: Liste(:)`?

Comment: No, because in the subroutine `liste` is a local variable declared as `type(ergebnis) :: Liste` (and there is no `allocatable` or `dimension` statement, so it's a scalar unallocatable variable).  If you wish to read further, then "scope" is a term you could look for.

Comment: @francescalus I see, of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You code is a little messed up, first you create one object

```
type(ergebnis) :: Liste
```

and then you want to use it like a array

```
Liste(i:1) = ergebnis(vorN, nachN, zeit(stu, minu, seku))
```

make Liste a arrray

```
type(ergebnis), allocatable :: Liste(:)
```

and then allocate it,

```
allocate(Liste(1:10), stat=status)
```

and don't forget to deallocate when you don't need Liste anymore

```
deallocate(Liste, stat=status)
```